# Downloading facebook video in android using webview javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating a Facebook video downloader app but I want to get playing video link
onLoadResource I want to get a video link on click listener.
Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "FBDownloader");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                        + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                        + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                        + "{"
                        + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                        + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                        + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                        + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                        + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick', 'FBDownloader.processVideo(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\");');"
                        + "}" + "}" + "})()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function prepareVideo() { "
                        + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                        + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                        + "{"
                        + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                        + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                        + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                        + "console.log(i);"
                        + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                        + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick', 'FBDownloader.processVideo(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\",\"'+jsonData['videoID']+'\");');"
                        + "}" + "}" + "})()");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:( window.onload=prepareVideo;"
                        + ")()");
            }
        });

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

        webView.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processVideo(final String vidData, final String vidID) {
        try {
            String mBaseFolderPath = android.os.Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator
                    + "FacebookVideos" + File.separator;
            if (!new File(mBaseFolderPath).exists()) {
                new File(mBaseFolderPath).mkdir();
            }
            String mFilePath = "file://" + mBaseFolderPath + "/" + vidID + ".mp4";

            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(vidData);
            DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
            req.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(mFilePath));
            req.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(req);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Download Failed: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But this code is not working fine. That's not returning any video link. I have tried many methods and searched on GitHub but I am failed. Can anyone suggest any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

are u sure that u are getting url in "vidID" the second parameter of ProcessVideo fun, i think you will get the downloadable link in "vidData" the 1st parameter..change first parameter in download process your code will start working fine....
**but one think that i want to mention this piece of  code will not work fine with android7 or above....**

Comment: That's my code working fine in the case of the Facebook story, but that's code not working on the home page.